# jQuery: Check if an element is assigned to a var

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a simple button manager to select and eventually unselect allready checked `img` elements which contains CSS class `.my_class`, why this doesn't work?

```
var last_selected;
$("img.my_class").click ( function () {
    if (last_selected != null) alert ($(this) == last_selected); // returns false everytime
    last_selected =  $(this);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you wrap `this` you create a new jQuery object. Two jQuery objects are not equal to each other just because they wrap the same element (`$(this) != $(this)`).

Instead, assign `this` itself to `last_selected` and everything should work as expected.

```
var last_selected;
$("img.my_class").click ( function () {
    if (last_selected != null) alert (this == last_selected);
    last_selected = this;
});
```

Comment: should probably use `===` in the comparison.

Comment: Would you mind giving me a hand over here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532009/placing-error-message-for-a-checkbox-array  ??

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because each time you call `$(this)` a new jQuery wrapper object is created.

Instead, try just saving "this":

```
var last_selected;
$("img.my_class").click ( function () {
  if (last_selected != null) alert (this === last_selected);
  last_selected =  this;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

why not assign a 'selected' class to the currently selected img?

```
$('img.my_class').click(function()
{
    // remove the selected class from the previous selected
    $('img.my_class.selected').removeClass('selected');
    // flag the current one as selected
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```