# jQuery: Differences between $(this) and this

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to understand what differences are between `$(this)` and `this` in `jQuery`, and eventually find a way to get `$(this)` object from `this` (`this` what??):

```
var last_btn;
$("#element").click (function () {
    if (last_btn != null && last_btn == this) {
        // to unselect the current button
        last_btn.removeClass ("selected"); // doesn't work because this is not $(this)
    } else {
        if (last_btn != null) last_btn.removeClass ("selected"); // to unselect another old button
        last_btn = this;
        $(this).addClass ("selected");
    }
});
```

As written in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058783/jquery-check-if-an-element-is-assigned-to-a-var), I need to use `this` instead of `$(this)` object because it's the only way to assign a `jQuery` object to a var without loose his instance.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the code you show, `this` is a reference to the pure DOM object with the ID `element` that got clicked.

`$(this)` will extend the DOM object into a [jQuery object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/), which makes all the jQuery goodness like `addClass` available for it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, so couldn't I get the jQuery object from the DOM object?

Comment: @Vittorio no, not without `$()`. The DOM object doesn't inherently contain the jQuery object. You have to use `$()` for jQuery to create the object first, based on the DOM object.

Answer (score 3):

@Pekka is right and I find this post to be important to post here by [Remy Sharp](http://remysharp.com/):

- [jQuery's this: demystified](http://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified/)